# Experiencing crash after upgrading to iOS SDK 4.14: [NSArray subarrayWithRange:]: range {0, 9223372036854775808} extends beyond bounds for empty array

Tags: ios, swiftui, dji-sdk

After upgrading to DJI iOS SDK v4.14, my pilot view crashes extremely frequently. Testing before iOS 14.4, this issue doesn't occur at all it seems. Anyone experience this? Here's the crash report:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x189ee986c __exceptionPreprocess + 220 (NSException.m:199)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x19ef04c50 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x189f59e1c _CFThrowFormattedException + 116 (CFObject.m:1994)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x189de0ff0 -[NSArray subarrayWithRange:] + 496 (NSArray.m:667)
4   DJIUXSDK                        0x102644cf0 -[DUXWidgetCollectionViewStacksLayout frameOfWidgetAtIndex:] + 324
5   DJIUXSDK                        0x102644b04 -[DUXWidgetCollectionViewStacksLayout layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:] + 244
6   DJIUXSDK                        0x1025682b0 -[DUXWidgetCollectionViewLayout layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:] + 316
7   UIKitCore                       0x18bfe76cc __45-[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:]_block_invoke + 224 (UICollectionViewData.mm:438)
8   UIKitCore                       0x18bfe6e54 -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:] + 1072 (UICollectionViewData.mm:587)
9   UIKitCore                       0x18bfb03c0 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 228 (UICollectionView.m:4367)
10  UIKitCore                       0x18cdebec4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2504 (UIView.m:17526)
11  QuartzCore                      0x18d306644 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 308 (CALayer.mm:10147)
12  QuartzCore                      0x18d306b18 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 524 (CALayer.mm:10014)
13  QuartzCore                      0x18d31b30c CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 144 (CALayer.mm:2485)
14  QuartzCore                      0x18d260640 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*) + 416 (CAContextInternal.mm:2449)
15  QuartzCore                      0x18d28bb08 CA::Transaction::commit() + 732 (CATransactionInternal.mm:449)
16  QuartzCore                      0x18d28ce98 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 96 (CATransactionInternal.mm:932)
17  CoreFoundation                  0x189e64358 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 36 (CFRunLoop.c:1799)
18  CoreFoundation                  0x189e5e5c4 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 576 (CFRunLoop.c:1912)
19  CoreFoundation                  0x189e5eb74 __CFRunLoopRun + 1056 (CFRunLoop.c:2953)
20  CoreFoundation                  0x189e5e21c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
21  GraphicsServices                0x1a1a2a784 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2259)
22  UIKitCore                       0x18c89eee8 -[UIApplication _run] + 1072 (UIApplication.m:3253)
23  UIKitCore                       0x18c8a475c UIApplicationMain + 168 (UIApplication.m:4707)
24  SoDro                           0x10026bdc4 main + 68 (AppDelegate.swift:15)
25  libdyld.dylib                   0x189b1e6b0 start + 4
```

Comment: What is `DUXWidgetCollectionViewStacksLayout.frameOfWidgetAtIndex` line 324?   Can you show that code?

Comment: @Paulw11 I believe it's referencing this: https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-UXSDK-iOS/blob/3515dbe125dd106242548d3d32a5464d2da09b74/Framework/DJIUXSDK.framework/Headers/DUXWidgetCollectionViewStacksLayout.h#L16

Comment: Then probably all you can do is log a bug against dji. The crash is in their collection view layout code